# Jarsigner is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, ionic2, jarsigner

I have an ionic application that I want to publish on the google play store. I have set the path, but I cant sign the unsigned apk. I am using a cmd to do this. My apk and my keystore are not in the same map. Maybe that is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You generate the signed APK within android studio itself. Go to Build -> Generate Signed APK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding  `jdk bin` folder to path in environment variables. it should look like this:

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin**

Inside this bin folder you can find all programs like `keytool`,`jarsigner` etc..

steps to sign the apk : refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065929/why-only-unsigned-apk-is-generated-with-ionic-cordova-build-command/44067641#44067641)

Comment: I have the keytool in the Program Files(x86). I think that that is the reason why it is not working. Let me try your solution

Comment: if your system is 64bit,  it will be programfiles otherwise it is x86..change the path and try

Comment: jarsigner: unable to recover key from keystore is the error im getting

Comment: make sure path for .apk file and keystore file are correct. and make sure password is correct

Comment: { path for .apk} just the apk name or... ?

Comment: best thing is to copy keystore and unsigned apk to projects root folder and do this `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore name_of_keystore.keystore unsigned_apk_file.apk alias_name`

Comment: if apk is in somewhere inside ex: android\build\output\apk, then give complete path to apk , otherwise if apk is in root folder, then no need of path

Comment: My apk is in another folder then the keystore. C:\Users\user\amcik\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk the apk is in here

Comment: copy that apk to the place where keystore is generated..no problem and type above command in comments

Comment: This is so annoying. I have done what you said but still same error :( The key store is in bin and the apk as well

Comment: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin both are in here

Comment: no man..you have to keep those files inside ionic app folder. not in jdk\bin folder..

Comment: I've done it like the screenshot still same error. Thanks for your effort btw

Comment: start creating from scratch..follow instructions in this onehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065929/why-only-unsigned-apk-is-generated-with-ionic-cordova-build-command/44067641#44067641

Comment: It says jar is signed, with a warning. the name of the apk is still unsigned, is that normal?

Comment: now you need zipalign tool to complete the process and after that you can see finalsigned apk there

Comment: zipalign -v 4 release-unsigned.apk new_apk_name.apk

Comment: It says: 'zipalign' is not recognized as an internal or externam command, bla bla

Comment: zip align will be available in android sdk\build tools..give that path in env variables..

Comment: Shall I put C:\Users\user\amcik\platforms\android\build in the env variables?

Comment: it should be lie this C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2;

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to sign your apk file using ionic. Go to platform -> android and keep your keystore file and release-signing.properties file. The release signing.properties file should be like 
`storeFile=***.keystore
keyAlias=***
storePassword=****
keyPassword=****`

after that you need to build with this command

> ionic build android --prod --release

then signed apk is generated in your apk folder. You dont need to execute jarsigner command every time. Just execute above command to sign apk file.After that put your apk file in latest build tools folder and zipalign it using

> zipalign -v 4 {signed apk file name}.apk  {output file name}.apk

then upload your output apk file into playstore

Comment: I have done everything on the ionic tutorial, but I only have to sign the apk.